# Error with Heroku/Discord.js "Service Unavailable"

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I found a weird error when trying to start my discord bot on heroku. So, earlier I decided to make a command handler for my bot so I can store commands in separate files, but I had several errors in the code. After posting a question here, one member helped me fix every single error that I got, but then I got a very unusual error that I have no idea what it means.

Here's the heroku log:

```
2020-11-09T15:09:58.846760+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Response: Service Unavailable
2020-11-09T15:09:58.846780+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at RequestHandler.execute (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:161:15)
2020-11-09T15:09:58.846780+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-11-09T15:09:58.846781+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async RequestHandler.push (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
2020-11-09T15:09:58.847016+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2020-11-09T15:09:58.847172+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here's the "index.js":

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Collection } = require ('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'TOKEN';
const PREFIX = '-';

const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online');
})

client.on('message', message=>{
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'help':
            client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

And "help.js" within my "commands" folder:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    execute(message, args){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(':scroll: │ Help List')
        .addField("Here is a list of commands:\n\n', '$save [name] ➝ Saves the current server template \n $load [link] ➝ Loads a template via link \n $cc [name] ➝ Creates a channel \n $dc [name] ➝ Deletes a channel \n $config [name]➝ Changes the server's name \n $mod [name] ➝ Adds/Removes the member from the moderator role \n $admin [name] ➝ Adds/Removes someone from the admin list")
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

I do not understand what this error comes from and it has no additional information. I restarted my dynos several times and also checked the status page of heroku, but everything seems file.
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You've titled this with "Server Unreliable" but the error message says "Service Unavailable"...?

Comment: Oops...that was a mistake. I fixed it now!

Comment: discord had some problems today regarding user login. I assume something similar is the issue here. Personally my bots work but I heard a few people had similar issues. I'd recommend to wait and see if it works tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and tell you tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Discord had a [pretty bad incident](https://discordstatus.com/incidents/029pzrz35sts) yesterday, which made it unavailable for most people.

Give it a try again today, it should work normally :)

Comment: Thanks, It's ok now